# Reference request for formula on global dimension

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra

Given a finite dimensional algebra $A$ over an algebraically closed field $K$.
Let $A^e=A^{op} \otimes_K A$ be the enveloping algebra of $A$.
Who noted first that the global dimension of $A$ is equal to the projective dimension of $A$ as $A^e$-module?
Earliest reference I can find is a paper by Happel, see https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0084073 .